# How to set Column width of QStandardItemModel in pyqt5

Tags: python, pyqt5

How to set the column width of a `QStandardItemModel` set to `QTableView`? I would also like to make it resizable by holding from the column edges.

Code:

```
reportContentsWidgetModel = QStandardItemModel(4, 4)

reportColumnNames = ["website", "https://neehack.com", "neehack.com", "pubs"]
reportContentsWidgetModel.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(reportColumnNames)
reportContentsWidget = QTableView()
reportContentsWidget.resizeColumnToContents(0)
reportContentsWidget.setModel(reportContentsWidgetModel)
```

I read a bunch of documentation but neither of them were clear on how to do it. So I don't even remember much of the things I tried.

Comment: move `reportContentsWidget.resizeColumnToContents(0)` after `setModel`

Comment: Alternatively, use `reportContentsWidget.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(0, QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)`, which will automatically resize the column (but will not allow resizing to the user). See the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qheaderview.html#setSectionResizeMode-1). Note that, just like `resizeColumnToContents()`, the function **must** be called only when the specified column actually exists (so, in your case, after setting the model); be aware that failing to do so can potentially be a cause of crash.

Comment: @eyllanesc but `resizeColumnToContents` doesn't allow to resize the column to you width of you wish. I want to be able to tell the how much should the column with be.

Comment: then use `self.reportContentsWidget.horizontalHeader().resizeSection(0, 100)` after `setModel`

Comment: @eyllanesc can you tell me how do I set the header column background Colors? I.e `website` background should be Gray or something

Comment: @hashy That question has nothing to do with your post so I will refrain from answering. Comments should refer to your post to ask for clarifications, improvements, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The help others having the same issue, you can:

if you want to columns width to stretch to tableview width you can:

```
reportContentsWidget.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(0, QHeaderView.Stretch)
```

If you want to set custom width, you can follow below as recommended by @eyllanesc:

```
self.reportContentsWidget.horizontalHeader().resizeSection(0, 100)
```

Comment: For future reference, please ensure you always explain yourself clearly in your questions and, if you want to provide your own answer (which is a *good* thing!), also ensure that it's not a duplicate. Your answer has *lots* of duplicates here on StackOverflow, and if you didn't find them (or we couldn't point you to them) it's just because: 1. your question was using a function order that wasn't correct, as pointed out in the first comment; 2. you didn't specify whether you wanted columns to dynamically adapt to the contents, adjust to the *existing* contents, or to a fixed width.

Comment: Also, it's important to understand that the "column width" is unrelated to the model. The *view* (in this case, the QTableView) decides the size of rows and columns, eventually based on what the model suggests, based on the [`SizeHintRole`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ItemDataRole-enum), which can also be completely ignored (it's a *hint*). I strongly urge you to study more carefully about the [MVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) pattern and the [Model-View](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html) pattern used by Qt.